# How do I read an SMS message sent to my Twilio phone number?

Tags: node.js, sms, twilio, twilio-api

I couldn't find this in Twilio's API docs.

I use NodeJS. When a user texts my Twilio number, I want to use NodeJS to retrieve the message.

Where can I find this in Twilio's API reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When a user texts your Twilio number there are two ways to get that message.

The first is the most efficient and uses webhooks. When you purchase your Twilio number you can configure a URL for [Twilio to make a request to every time it receives an SMS for that number](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request). The request will include a bunch of parameters, including the number the message is from and the body of the message. You can receive the request with a Node.js app, here's a quick example using express:

```
var app = require("express")();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false});

app.post("/messages", function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body.Body); // the message body
  console.log(req.body.From); // the number that sent the message
  res.send("<Response/>"); // send an empty response (you can also send messages back)
});

app.listen(3000); // listens on port 3000
```

When developing an app that uses webhooks like this, [I recommend tunneling to your local machine using ngrok](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/09/6-awesome-reasons-to-use-ngrok-when-testing-webhooks.html).

The other way to get your messages is by using [Twilio's REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest). You can list all the messages to your numbers using the [messages resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message). In Node.js, this would look like:

```
var client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.messages.list(function(err, data) {
    data.messages.forEach(function(message) {
        console.log(message.body);
    });
});
```

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: Is `authToken` then same as my client secret?

Comment: Your auth token is found on your [Twilio console](https://www.twilio.com/console) underneath your Account SID.

Comment: I sent some texts to my Twilio number. Then I tried your second block of code suggestion, but got this error when running  `nodejs app.js`, which is where my code is. I'm using Debian Jessis 8.2 with NodeJS v4.6. `node_modules/twilio/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'messages' of undefined`

Comment: You may have an error there then. Try logging the `err` argument out and seeing what has gone wrong.

Comment: I get this object when I `console.log(err)`: `{ status: 401,
  message: 'Authenticate',
  code: 20003,
  moreInfo: 'https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20003' }`

Comment: That authentication error does suggest your account sid and auth token may be wrong. Can you double check and try again?

Comment: Ah, I had to use the Account ID string beginning with "AC" for the `accountSid`